# Laravel eloquent relations in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

I have a setup like this.

**Book** Model

```
public function bookShelf()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\bookShelf');
}
```

and **BookShelf** model has this

```
public function book()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Book');
}
```

Now the question is how can I access this relation in my front-end using Angularjs?

I have already tried this method.

```
BookShelf::with('book')->find($id);
```

But this is not the best scenario to do this, because I have other relations willing to access as well.

What I want is-- Simply, upon selection of a `bookshelf` in the front-end, a dropdown displays all the `books` the `bookshelf` has.

Someone please help me out with this.

Comment: What other relations willing to access? I don't really understand what wrong with your solution..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can lazy load the books per bookshelf dropdown?

This requires an API endpoint that takes the Bookshelf Id and returns a JSON representation of all the books.

Comment: Could you please provide me some sample on how to do this?

Comment: Google is your friend. Return JSON from a controller & API endpoint dedicated to that. And make requests to that API endpoint from Angular.